# My function for printing matrixes is returning random numbers

Tags: c

I have to create a code which prints a matrix, but it isn't working. When I run this it returns a matrix in which all numbers are 6356700.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Here I create a function for printing a matrix
void print(int n[][5], int size) {
    //Here I print the matrix
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++ ) {
        for (int j=0; j<=4; j++) {
            printf("%d ", n[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    //I create a matrix
    int lanadelrey[5][5] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25};
    //And print it using the function
    print(lanadelrey,5);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("%d ", n[i]);` - you forgot another index. Do you see any compiler warnings? You should see a bunch.

Comment: Your compiler should be warning you about `printf("%d ", n[i]);`: *"format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'int *'"*

Answer (score 0):

Change the print statement:`printf("%d ", n[i]);` to `printf("%d ", n[i][j]);`